# Angular 5 sharing components between lazy loaded modules broken the routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, lazy-loading

I am developing somewhat large application using angular 5 with several modules. Each modules has loaded as lazy loading mechanism of Angular 5. 
I am sharing components between those modules and they are working fine.
But I am having an issue with loading module root as follows.

**App module routing**

```
export const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: MenuComponent },
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
  { path: 'sample', loadChildren: 'app/modules/sample/sample.module#SampleModule' },
  { path: 'membership', loadChildren: 'app/modules/membership/membership.module#MembershipModule' },
  { path: 'class', loadChildren: 'app/modules/class/class.module#ClassModule' },

  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }

];
```

I am sharing components inside ClassModule, in AdminModule.

**Class Module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    ClassRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ClassRoutingComponents,
    ClassHomeComponent,
    ClassListComponent,
    ClassCalendarComponent,
    AddNewCalssComponent,
    ClassScheduleComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ClassRoutingComponents,
    ClassHomeComponent,
    ClassListComponent,
    AddNewCalssComponent,
    ClassScheduleComponent
  ],
  providers: [

  ]
})
export class ClassModule {}
```

**AdminModule has imported ClassModule as follows.**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    ClassModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AdminRoutingComponents,
    .......
  ],
  providers:
    [
      AdminService,

    ]
})

export class AdminModule { }
```

**Class Routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ClassHomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**Admin Routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AdminHomeComponent },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
...
}
```

Every components has shared works fine but my problem is when I am routing to `http://localhost:4200/admin` it loades `ClassHomeComponent` but it must load `AdminHomeComponent`

Answer (score 2):

`ClassModule` imports `ClassRoutingModule` and `AdminModule` imports `ClassModule`.

So when you are lazy loading `AdminModule` (via `loadChildren: 'app/modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'`) the router is pulling in routes from `ClassModule` first, and honoring them.  Hence your `/admin` route is loading the component defined for root in `ClassRoutingModule` (`ClassHomeComponent`)